# dynamically arrange array for chartjs

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, chart.js

I'm trying to prepare data from json dynamically for chartjs.
The data is received form a sql database.
Now I'm trying to display the data in CHARTJS for different ORDERS.

For different PROJECTS there is a different amount of ORDERS.
The DATE within a PROJECT/data has always the same start and end date and the same amount of dates.

My received **data ** for a PROJECT looks like this:

```
0:{DATE: 2023-04-09, HOURS: '.5' ORDER: 111}
1:{DATE: 2023-04-10, HOURS: '2'  ORDER: 111}
2:{DATE: 2023-04-11, HOURS: '1.8' ORDER: 111}
...
10:{DATE: 2023-04-09, HOURS: '.0' ORDER: 221}
11:{DATE: 2023-04-10, HOURS: '18' ORDER: 221}
12:{DATE: 2023-04-11, HOURS:  '9' ORDER: 221}
...
20:{DATE: 2023-04-09, HOURS: '.7' ORDER: 115}
21:{DATE: 2023-04-10, HOURS:  '5' ORDER: 115}
22:{DATE: 2023-04-11, HOURS:  '1' ORDER: 115}
```

Now I want to bring the Data in different arrays to display them in one Line-CHARTJS.
Manually there is no problem:

```
  var HOURS1=[];
    for(var i in data) {
    if (data[i].ORDER== '111'){
    HOURS1.push(data[i].HOURS)};
 }

   var HOURS2=[];
    for(var i in data) {
    if (data[i].ORDER== '221'){
    HOURS2.push(data[i].HOURS)};
 }
...

var chartdata = {
        labels: uniqueDATES,
      
        datasets : [
          {
            label: '111',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: HOURS1
          },
           {
            ...
           }
         ]}
```

What I was able to reach so far is to get an array with different ORDER numbers and to loop through them but I'm not able to push them in dynamic variables.  I also got an array with the DATES for the x-axis.

```
const allorders = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.ORDER))];
 
   allorders.forEach((k) => {
      const ho=[];

       for(var i in data) {
       if (data[i].ORDER== k){
       ho.push(data[i].hour)};
 }
console.log(ho)
})
```

This actually brings the right result in the console but it is not saved and I can't dipaly it with CHARTJS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant by dynamic in this context, but since you said you got the right result with the console, I'm assuming that you want to update the dataset for an instantiated chartjs.

If that's the case, what you gonna have to do is update the actual chartjs instance with the new data, just updating the array will not trigger any reactivity.

From the code you have, you can create a new dataset, and you can use the array function `reduce` for that:

```js
const allorders = Array.from(new Set(data.map(item => item.ORDER)));

const hours = allorders.reduce((accumulator, currentOrder) => {
  const selectedOrder = data.find(order => order == currentOrder);
  if (selectedOrder) {
    return [...accumulator, selectedOrder.hour];
  }
  return accumulator;
}, []);
```

What this code does is actually create a new array, you can then add this to your dataset at the chartjs instance.

If you just push data to an array that is used by chartjs by reference, it can not react to this change and you have to manually tell chartjs to update the data and redraw the canvas.

One way of doing this is using the action `update` of the chartjs instance, you have an example at the documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#update-mode